# Bank Reserve ratio

Tags: macroeconomics, banking, reserve-requirement-ratio

It's known that the money multiplier is 7 and the ratio of cash held by the public to their deposits is 1 to 20. Which of the following must be the bank's reserve ratio?

My attempt,
Money multiplier=1/reserve ratio
Reserve ratio=1/7

But the given answer is 0.1. Why?